# fxcop execution failed with return code '9' while running sonar

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop

I am using sonar code analysis tool for analyzing my c# language projects..  It is working fine for some projects. But for some projects, while uploading in sonar, i am getting Fxcop execution failed with return code '9' or '513' or '12' and saying that execution failure...

Answer (score 0):

Check FxCop documentation about exit codes to know more about those failures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164705%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Fxcop error code 9 means that Fxcop analysis was failed for one of the dll or project in the solution.
Sometimes Fxcop Analysis failed for some projects in the solution due to various reasons. One of the reason may be that Fxcop requires some DLLs to complete the analysis. In this case the Fxcop analysis for complete solution gets failed and Fxcop exits with error code 9. This results in failure of complete sonar analysis.

Solution: We can make use of the sonar property sonar.fxcop.assemblies to run Fxcop analysis.Provide the comma separated paths of only those dll as this property value on which we want to run Fxcop analysis.

eg: sonar.fxcop.assemblies=path of dll1,path of dll2

Put this property in the sonar.properties file which resides in the same directory in which solution file lies. Don't provide the path of dll which is causing failure.

Since Fxcop will not do analysis on the problematic dll, the sonar analysis will not exit now with the error message "FxCop execution failed with return code 9 in sonar."

For complete problem reason , analysis and solution [click here](http://counsellingbyabhi.blogspot.in/2013/06/FxcoperrorCode9inSonar.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this error by checking the FxCop report file (fxcop-report.xml, in my case it was stored in the .sonar folder, under my projects root folder).

In this file I could to see that the problem was with a rule not being loaded (CA2001) and, then, a object null reference happened.

I changed the FxCop instalation, from my standalone instalation do Visual Studio's instalation. The versions were differente. 
Problem solved.